# Why i am getting error of adress family not supported by protocol?

Tags: c++, sockets

I am implementing two way communications using UDP protocol , intitially i send a message HELO from client to server which successfully displays on server side but when i send message from server to client in reply of HELO so it gives me error: Address family not supported by protocol.

Here's my server code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>



using namespace std;
int main(void)
    {
    char write[100];
    int MAXBUFLEN=100;
    char* buf;
    char msg[100];
    char swp;
    int l,x,y;

    int conn_sock,n,err;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr,client_addr;

    conn_sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    if(conn_sock == -1)
    {
    perror("\n\nError in making socket and error is");

    cout<<"Error No:\t\n"<<errno;
    exit(0);
    }

    server_addr.sin_family= AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = 1234;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    err=bind(conn_sock,(struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,sizeof(server_addr)); // binding...

    if(err == -1)
    {

    perror("\n\nError in binding and error is:");
    cout<<"Error No:\t\n"<<errno;
    exit(0);
    }
    int s=sizeof(client_addr);

    n=recvfrom(conn_sock,msg,sizeof(msg),0,(struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,(socklen_t*)s); // reciving HELO from client..


    cout<<msg<<endl;

    cout<<"The messgae hasbeen recieved from client now enter a reply for HELO msg:"<<endl;
    cin>> write;

    // sending reply to client

    int m=sendto(conn_sock,write,strlen(write),0,(sockaddr *)&client_addr,s); // sending reply to client on reply of helo...
    if (m== -1){
     perror("talker: sendto");
    }
    // now recieve mail fromm...

    recvfrom(conn_sock,msg,sizeof(msg),0,(struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,(socklen_t*)s);

// sending rcpto client
    sendto(conn_sock,write,strlen(write),0,(sockaddr *)&client_addr,s);
    recvfrom(conn_sock,msg,sizeof(msg),0,(struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,(socklen_t*)s);
    cout<<"Recpt to: Nu.edu.pk"<<endl;  
    exit(0);

}
```

And here's my client code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define SERVERPORT "4950"    // the port users will be connecting to
#define MAXBUFLEN 100
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char*argv[])

{

    // declarations
    char msg3[]="DATA";
    int sockfd;
        struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
        int rv;
        int numbytes;
        char buf[MAXBUFLEN];
        socklen_t addr_len;
        struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
    char* bigarray;
    char msg[]="HELO";
    char msg2[]="Mail from: Mahnoorfatima@gmail.com";   
    int i=0;

    char * adress;
    char * subject;
    char * name;
    const char *delim="@";
    // getting commandline args into arrays.
    adress=argv[i+1];
    char* host=strtok(adress,delim );
    subject=argv[i+2];
    name=argv[i+3];


    // putting all in one array

    bigarray=adress;
    bigarray=subject;
    bigarray=name;




    if(argc>9){
    cout << "Just provide three arguments in commandline,please. " << endl;
        }

    // gets the name of the host:

    int a=gethostname(bigarray, 100);

    cout<<"The host of the client is:"<<a<<endl;


    int conn_sock,n,m,err;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    conn_sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

    if(conn_sock ==-1)
    {
    perror("\n\nError in making socket and error is");

    cout<<"Error No:\t\n"<<errno;
    exit(0);
    }


    server_addr.sin_family= AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = 1234;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");


    int pp=sizeof(server_addr);
    n=sendto(conn_sock,msg,strlen(msg),0,(sockaddr *)&server_addr,pp);//sending HELO to server...

    n=recvfrom(conn_sock,msg,sizeof(msg),0,(struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,(socklen_t*)pp);
    cout<<"Mail from: mahnoorfatima22@gmail.com"<<endl;
    n=sendto(conn_sock,msg2,strlen(msg2),0,(sockaddr *)&server_addr,pp);


        // sending file to server

    // reieving from server rcpto command

    recvfrom(conn_sock,msg,sizeof(msg),0,(struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,(socklen_t*)pp);   

    // sending data command to the server....

    n=sendto(conn_sock,msg3,strlen(msg3),0,(sockaddr *)&server_addr,pp);
        //Sending the filename to server...
        if ((n = sendto(sockfd,name,strlen(name), 0,p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen)) == -1) {
        //     perror("Error is sending");
                exit(1);
                                                }              
        //     Get the size of the file server sy 

    addr_len = sizeof their_addr;
        if ((n = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, MAXBUFLEN-1 , 0,(struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_len)) == -1) {
        //     perror("Error in recieving file");
         exit(1);
                                                        }


        cout<<"client: recieved file size: %s\nNumbytes:%d\n"<<buf<<numbytes;





    exit(0);

    }
```

Comment: Check your `recvfrom` calls, and compare them with the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvfrom.2.html). The casting you have actually hides a very serious case of *undefined behavior*. Using casting to shut-up compiler warnings is really the wrong way to solve the warnings.

Comment: it gives me warning only that's not the issue...

Comment: cout<<"The messgae hasbeen recieved from client now enter a reply for HELO msg:"<<endl;
    cin>> write;

    // sending reply to client

    int m=sendto(conn_sock,write,strlen(write),0,(sockaddr *)&client_addr,s); // sending reply to client on reply of helo...
    if (m== -1){
     perror("talker: sendto");
    } My this messgae doesnt goes from server to client do u know why? It gives me error. Please help me

Comment: Oh but it *is* an issue, a very serious issue as all undefined behavior is! Hiding it doesn't make it less of an issue. Also, one consequence of having undefined behavior in your code is that it make your whole program unreliable and suspect.

Comment: okay i am resolving it but can u tell me why i am getting error when sending from server to client?

Comment: Not your problem but this line :-

server_addr.sin_port = 1234;
The port number needs to be in network byte order (So you might have to use ntoa on it). You are using this on both sides so it will probably "work" but not using the port you exopect.

Comment: You also have problems with your strings, you do not send the terminator, and you do not add it when you receive the data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely that the `recvfrom` function expects a *pointer* to the socket address structure size, while you provide the length by value. That means that the compiler with think that the size you set (`sizeof(client_addr)`) is interpreted as a pointer, and whatever the structure size is, it's not a valid pointer or pointing to something remotely valid.

That means that the `recvfrom` might not fill in the peer address structure (`client_addr`) completely, which leads to your `sendto` failure.

Try e.g. this instead:

```
n=recvfrom(conn_sock,msg,sizeof(msg),0,
          (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,&s);
//                                        ^
//                                        |
//            Note address-of operator here
```

Comment: it gives me error :  ssize_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
                        struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen);

Comment: @MahNoor Use the correct type to begin with: `socklen_t s  = sizeof(client_addr);`.

Comment: i got that resolved but my message send from server to client is not displaying on server's side client: cout<<"The messgae hasbeen recieved from client now enter a reply for HELO msg:"<<endl;
 cin>> write;

 if(sendto(conn_sock, write,strlen(write), 0,(sockaddr*)&client_addr, sizeof(client_addr))==-1){
     perror("sendto");

Comment: and client:     cout<<"Display the message send from server- clinet"<<endl;
 
 int nn=recvfrom(conn_sock,amsg,sizeof(amsg),0,(struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,&pp);
 
 if(nn== -1){
 perror("recvfrom:");
 }